# Pagination in Lightning Table

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, pagination

I am facing issue while doing pagination, each page displays 10 records. The records are getting displayed only when i click on next button, before that it just shows me total number of pages as below:[image: This is how it gets displayed right now]

Lightning Comp

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride" controller = "SearchController" access="global" >

<aura:attribute name="searchResult" type="List" description="store and display account list return from server"/>

<aura:attribute name="searchResultSAP" type="List" description="store and display account list return from server"/>

 <!-- searchKeyword,searchKeyword1,searchKeyword2,searchKeyword3,searchKeyword4 variable are created in order to 
    search records when either of the input fields are entered -->
<aura:attribute name="searchKeyword" type="String" description="use for store user search input"/>
<aura:attribute name="searchKeyword1" type="String" description="use for store user search input"/>
<aura:attribute name="searchKeyword2" type="String" description="use for store user search input"/>
<aura:attribute name="searchKeyword3" type="String" description="use for store user search input"/>
<aura:attribute name="picvalue" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="searchKeyword4" type="String" description="use for store user search input"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordTypeName" type="String" default=""/>
<aura:attribute name ="recordTypeId" type="String" default=""/>
<aura:attribute name="displayEndUserButton" type="boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:attribute type="Integer" name="pageNumber" default="1" required="true" />
<aura:attribute type="Integer" name="maxPage" default="1" required="true" />
<aura:attribute type="String" name="sortField" />
<aura:attribute type="Boolean" name="sortAsc" />
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageNumber}" action="{!c.renderPage}" />
<aura:attribute type="Account[]" name="currentList" />

<!--Declare Handler-->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/> 

<!-- SHOW LOADING SPINNER--> 
<lightning:spinner variant="brand" size="large" aura:id="Id_spinner" class="slds-hide" />
<div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
    <!--<aura:attribute name="newAccount" type="Object"/> -->

    <div class="slds-page-header">
        <div class="slds-grid">
            <lightning:icon iconName="standard:account" size="medium"/>
            <div class="slds-col slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                <p class="slds-text-title_caps slds-line-height_reset">Account</p>
                <h1 class="slds-page-header__title slds-m-right_small slds-align-middle slds-truncate"  title="My Account"> Account Search</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <lightning:layout>
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
            <div class="header-column">
                <p class="field-title" title="Field 4"><strong>Account Search</strong></p>
            </div>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
            <div class="header-column">
                <p class="field-title" title="Field 4"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="{!c.resetSearchStatus}">Reset Search</a></p>
            </div>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>

    <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="space">
        <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
            <div class="header-column">   
                <p class="field-title" title="Search by">Search by</p>
                <p>Search Criteria: </p>
            </div>    
        </lightning:layoutItem>

        <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
            <lightning:input aura:id="searchField"  type="text" value="{!v.searchKeyword}"  Name="Last Name" label ="Account Name"/>
        </lightning:layoutItem>

        <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
            <lightning:input aura:id="searchField" type="text" value="{!v.searchKeyword1}" Name="Address" label ="Address"/>
        </lightning:layoutItem>  
        <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
            <lightning:input aura:id="searchField"  type="text" value="{!v.searchKeyword2}" Name="City" label ="City"/>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
            <lightning:input aura:id="searchField"  type="text" value="{!v.searchKeyword3}" Name="Zip" label ="Zip"/>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
            <lightning:select value="{!v.searchKeyword4}" label="State">
                <option value="">--None--</option>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.picvalue}" var="s">
                    <option value="{!s}">{!s}</option>
                </aura:iteration>
            </lightning:select>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>

    <!-- TOTAL RECORDS BADGES
    <div class="slds-m-around_x-small">
        <lightning:badge label="{!v.TotalNumberOfRecord}" />
    </div> -->

    <!-- ERROR MESSAGE IF NOT RECORDS FOUND--> 
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.Message}">
        <div class="slds-notify_container slds-is-relative">
            <div class="slds-notify slds-notify_toast slds-theme_error" role="alert">
                <div class="slds-notify__content">
                    <h2 class="slds-text-heading_small">No Records Found...</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aura:if>
    <lightning:layout>
        <lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Search for Account" title="search action" onclick="{!c.Search}"/>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
    <div class="slds-p-top_large">
        <div class="slds-page-header">
            <div class="slds-grid">
                <div class="slds-col slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                    <p class="slds-page-header__title slds-m-right_small slds-align-middle slds-truncate">Accounts Already in Salesforce</p>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-button-group" role="group">
                    <div class="slds-p-right_xx-small">
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.displayEndUserButton}">
                            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Create End User Account" title="Brand action" onclick="{!c.createEndUserAccount}" />
                        </aura:if>  
                    </div>     
                    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Cancel" title="Brand action" onclick="{!c.cancelButton}" />

                    <!--  <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral"> Create End User Account </button>-->
                    <!-- <button variant="brand" class="slds-button slds-button_neutral"> Cancel </button>-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- TABLE CONTENT--> 
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                <th scope="col">
                    <div onclick="{!c.sortByName}" class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Account Name <aura:if isTrue="{!v.sortField=='Name'}">
                        <span>
                            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.sortAsc}">
                                &#8593;
                                <aura:set attribute="else">
                                    &#8595;
                                </aura:set>
                            </aura:if>
                        </span>
                    </aura:if></div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div onclick="{!c.sortByIndustry}" class="slds-truncate" title="Record Type ID">Record Type ID <aura:if isTrue="{!v.sortField=='RecordType'}">
                        <span>
                            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.sortAsc}">
                                &#8593;
                                <aura:set attribute="else">
                                    &#8595;
                                </aura:set>
                            </aura:if>
                        </span>
                    </aura:if></div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div onclick="{!c.sortByAnnualRevenue}" class="slds-truncate" title="Street">Street  <aura:if isTrue="{!v.sortField=='CityAdd'}">
                        <span>
                            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.sortAsc}">
                                &#8593;
                                <aura:set attribute="else">
                                    &#8595;
                                </aura:set>
                            </aura:if>
                        </span>
                    </aura:if></div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="City">City</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="State">State</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Postal Code">Postal Code</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Selling Territory">Selling Territory</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
            <!--### display all records of searchResult attribute by aura:iteration ###-->
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.currentList}" var="acc" indexVar="count">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate"><a href="{!'/one/one.app?#/sObject/'+ acc.Id + '/view'}" target="_top">{!acc.Name}</a></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.RecordType.Name}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.BillingStreet}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.BillingCity}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.BillingState}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.BillingPostalCode}</div>
                    </td> 
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate"><a href="{!'/one/one.app?#/sObject/'+ acc.Territory__r.Id + '/view'}" target="_top">{!acc.Territory__r.Name}</a></div>
                    </td> 
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration> 
        </tbody>
          <div class="slds-button-group" role="group">
                <button onclick="{!c.prevPage}" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral">
                    Prev
                </button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral">
                    {!v.pageNumber} / {!v.maxPage}
                </button>
                <button onclick="{!c.nextPage}" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral">
                    Next
                </button>
            </div>
    </table>
  </div>
```

JSController

```
({
//Load Account Industry Picklist
doInit: function(component, event, helper) { 
    var pickvar = component.get("c.getPickListValuesIntoList");
    pickvar.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
            var list = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.picvalue", list);
        }
        else if(state === 'ERROR'){
            alert('ERROR OCCURED.');
        }
    })
    $A.enqueueAction(pickvar);
},

Search : function(component, event, helper) {
    var searchField = component.find('searchField');
    helper.SearchHelper(component, event);  
    helper.sortBy(component, "Name");
    event.preventDefault();    
},


resetSearchStatus : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.searchKeyword","");
    component.set("v.searchKeyword1","");
    component.set("v.searchKeyword2","");
    component.set("v.searchKeyword3","");
    component.set("v.searchKeyword4","");
},

createAccountUsingSAP: function(component, event, helper) {
},  
cancelButton : function (component, event, helper) {
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
        "url": "/lightning/o/Account/home"
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
},

prevPage: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.pageNumber", Math.max(component.get("v.pageNumber")-1, 1));
},
nextPage: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.pageNumber", Math.min(component.get("v.pageNumber")+1, component.get("v.maxPage")));
},
sortByName: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.sortBy(component, "Name");
},
sortByIndustry: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.sortBy(component, "RecordType");
},
sortByAnnualRevenue: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.sortBy(component, "CityAdd");
},
renderPage: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.renderPage(component);
}
```

})

Helper

```
({    
SearchHelper: function(component, event) {

    component.find("Id_spinner").set("v.class" , 'slds-show');

    var action = component.get("c.fetchAccountRecords");
    action.setParams({
        'searchKeyWord': component.get("v.searchKeyword"),
        'searchKeyWord1': component.get("v.searchKeyword1"),
        'searchKeyWord2': component.get("v.searchKeyword2"),
        'searchKeyWord3': component.get("v.searchKeyword3"),
        'searchKeyWord4': component.get("v.searchKeyword4"),
        'recId': component.get("v.recordId")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        component.find("Id_spinner").set("v.class" , 'slds-hide');
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {  
            component.set ("v.displayEndUserButton",true);
            var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();
            if (storeResponse.length == 0) {
                component.set("v.Message", true);
            } else {
                component.set("v.Message", false);
            }
            component.set("v.searchResult", storeResponse); 
            component.set("v.maxPage", Math.floor((storeResponse.length+9)/10));

            var action2 = component.get("c.searchSAP");
            action2.setParams({

                'nameToSearch': component.get("v.searchKeyword"),
                'addressToSearch': component.get("v.searchKeyword1"),
                'cityToSearch': component.get("v.searchKeyword2"),
                'zipToSearch': component.get("v.searchKeyword3"),
                'stateToSearch': component.get("v.searchKeyword4"),
            });
            debugger;
            action2.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                var state1 = response.getState();
                if (state1 === "SUCCESS") {
                    var storeResponseSAP = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
                    component.set("v.searchResultSAP", storeResponseSAP); 
                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action2);    
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

sortBy: function(component, field) {
    var sortAsc = component.get("v.sortAsc"),
        sortField = component.get("v.sortField"),
        records = component.get("v.searchResult");
    sortAsc = sortField != field || !sortAsc;
    records.sort(function(a,b){
        var t1 = a[field] == b[field],
            t2 = (!a[field] && b[field]) || (a[field] < b[field]);
        return t1? 0: (sortAsc?-1:1)*(t2?1:-1);
    });
    component.set("v.sortAsc", sortAsc);
    component.set("v.sortField", field);
    component.set("v.searchResult", records);
    this.renderPage(component);
},

renderPage: function(component) {
    var records = component.get("v.searchResult"),
        pageNumber = component.get("v.pageNumber"),
        pageRecords = records.slice((pageNumber-1)*10, pageNumber*10);
    component.set("v.currentList", pageRecords);
}
```

})

Comment: You should call helper.sortBy() function inside the callback of "fetchAccountRecords" action  ,the function is getting called before the call gets complete

Comment: @User6670 That seems like the solution - want to flesh out in an answer post?

Comment: Thanks @User6670
Initially i did the same but with wrong syntax, but after you put me in right direction it worked smoothly.
Inside "fetchAccountRecords" callback i have called helper.sortBy() function as below:

this.sortBy(component, "Name");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call helper.sortBy() function inside the callback of  "fetchAccountRecords" action the function is getting executed before the call gets complete.Javascript has a callstack where it handle all the calls  without blocking the rest of the code ,hence your function helper.sortBy() gets executed before the call is complete.